# Transform assosiative array to index array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have to following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [clave_su] => CAD
        [nombre_su] => CENTRO DE APOYO AL DIAGNOSTICO
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [clave_su] => CADIT
        [nombre_su] => CENTRO DE APOYO AL DIAGNOSTICO E INGENIERIA TISULAR
    )
```

What i am expecting is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CAD
            [1] => CENTRO DE APOYO AL DIAGNOSTICO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CADIT
            [1] => CENTRO DE APOYO AL DIAGNOSTICO E INGENIERIA TISULAR
        )
)
```

What i tried is the use of the array_values function of PHP.

But i cant get it work..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($array as $&item) {
    $item = array_values($item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!I just added array_push($noAssociativeArray,$item); to create my new array. Good day

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = array_values($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just walk the original array and strip out the keys using `array_values()`.  that might look like this:

```
// your initial array
$array = array(
    array(
        'clave_su' => 'CAD',
        'nombre_su' => 'CENTRO DE APOYO AL DIAGNOSTICO'
    ),
    array(...),
    ...
);
// transform inner arrays to be numerically indexed
array_walk($array, function(&$sub_array, $key_not_used) {
    $sub_array = array_values($sub_array);
});
```

Comment: Needless step with `array_walk`.  Just `array_map` the `array_values`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes. That is suitable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the solutions using `array_keys`, this snippet ensures that the transformation from keys to index is always the same. This means that if a certain key is missing for an entry, or if the definition order isn't the same accross all entries, you always access the same data with a given index.

```
function array_assoc2index ($input) {
    $output = array();
    $keycount = 0;
    $keys = array();

    foreach ($input as $val) {
        $a = array();
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($keys[$k]))
                $keys[$k] = $keycount++;
            $a[$keys[$k]] = $v;
        }

        $output[] = $a;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest one-liner:

```
$array = array_map('array_values', $array);
```